# How to insert data from one database table to another database table?

Tags: mysql

I have to MySQL databases **DB1** and **DB2**, DB1 is on **Online** server, and DB2 is on **local machine**(localhost), Now i want to insert some data into DB2's table named **db2_table** from DB1's table named **db1_table** using **SQL QUERY**. So how it is possible?

Comment: you need two connections, `$con1` for `DB1` to get data & `$con2` for `DB2` to insert data that you get from `DB1`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible with one SQL Query. A SQL-Query can only be executed on one server and he doesn't know the second server. So you have to do this with an application or you have to use the import and export functions of MySql Workbench or PHPMyAdmin.

Here you can find a very similar question:

[insert into a MySQL database on a different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955760/insert-into-a-mysql-database-on-a-different-server)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to create 2 simultaneous connections as suggested by @Being Human - and write one query - which would be ideal.  However the method below works for me.

1: make a dump file of `DB1` from online server

```
mysqldump -u <db_username> -h <db_host> -p db_name table_name > backup.sql
```

2: restore dumpfile to local server and database (will restore to same DB)

```
mysql -u<db_username> -p DB_NAME < backup.sql
```

3: INSERT into `db2_table` from `db1_table`

```
INSERT INTO DB2.db2_table (<col1>, <col2>, <col3>....) 
    SELECT <col1>, <col2>, <col3> ... 
    FROM db1_table;
```

Making sure the columns returned by the SELECT subquery on `db1_table` maps into the columns in the `db2_table`