# Insert data from 1 mysql database on a local server to a different one on a remote server

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, database

I have two database one is at client side and one is running at another machine (which i am using a remote database). I have to send a table data from client database to my remote database. But problem is if I use this code:

```
mysql_query(con, " select * from DB.Table1")
```

this function only works for Database (client side) and don't connect with my remote database. Its mean only 1 connection is possible at a time. I am doing it in C++ do you have any solution. ?

Comment: Wouldn't the `con` argument identify which connection you want to use? What is the problem with creating two connection objects?

Comment: what if i create two connection with separate mysql_query() query then how can i retrieve and store in remote DB ?

Comment: Here is an old somewhat related link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955760/insert-into-a-mysql-database-on-a-different-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955760/insert-into-a-mysql-database-on-a-different-server)

Comment: Seems logical: 1) Read a row from a SELECT query into a C++ datastructure,  2) execute an INSERT query on the other server. Which step are you having trouble with?

Comment: Can you create a shared server on one of the instances? Then you can hit both locations in a single query.